# How to pull from a self hosted gitlab repository using gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a self-hosted gitlab instance running on docker windows with that I have set up a runner for building the gitlab-ci. In my gitlab-ci.yml file, I have mentioned that every time there is a commit to the git repository then the runner should to **pull the latest source from the repository**. My gitlab-ci file has the following lines:

```
git_pull:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo 'creating a pull request'
        - cd "C:\Users\Haroon Gul\STM32CubeIDE\workspace_1.0.2\my-test-project"
        - git pull "http://localhost:9090/root/my-test-project.git"
```

Every time this step runs i get the following output `Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.`

I am using shell runner on windows.

Comment: This may help: https://help.github.com/en/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use